# Project Architecture

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I was wondering if I did a good choice concerning my project conception. I am not an expert and it's the reason why I want to know the different views of the other developers.

My project is separate in two Bundles :

- FrontOfficeBundle
- BackOfficeBundle

I want to access my different objects from everywhere. Until now, I duplicated them, but I think it's not the best thing to do.

So how can I access an object at the front office if this one is implemented in the BackOfficeBundle ?
Can anyone enlighten me ? Thank you.

Comment: What stops you from accessing classes implemented in `BackOfficeBundle` from `FrontOfficeBundle`? As long as you have proper package structure (that is PHP knows how to map namespace prefix to a directory) you're good to go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just use same classes in both bundles, you should use this architecture inspired from the `symfony` architecture

```
  src
   | myvendorname
        |Bundles
            | FrontOfficeBundle
            | BackOfficeBundle
        |Components
            | MyMutualClasses1
            | MyMutualClasses2
```

Or if you use the SAME services in both bundles, declare the services in your MutualBundle ( Be aware that FrontOfficeBundle has a depency toward MutualBundle. Same for BackOfficeBundle )

```
  src
   | myvendorname
        |Bundles
            | FrontOfficeBundle
            | BackOfficeBundle
            | MutualBundle
```